# iphone: How to store large number of photos?

Tags: iphone

I want to make a photo management app on iPhone (somehow similar to the built-in "Photos" app). The app will be able to handle large amount of photos and manage different photo categories such as "landscape", "portrait", "nature", "people", etc. And it will also allow users to delete photos, change categories,...

**The question is, what is the good way to store that large amount of photos?**

Initially I thought of storing the photos on SQLite. But I heard many recommendations on this website not to use SQLite for large number of photos for performance reason.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to use [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/macosx/coredata.html) to manage the metadata for your photos and store the actual images themselves [on disk](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000055-SW1). If there's any question about whether to use Core Data or SQLite, you should use Core Data.